# haproxy tls alert decrypt error

Tags: ssl, haproxy, alert

I'm using haproxy 1.8.17 and openssl 1.1.1a from Debian testing to serve TLS 1.2 connections with client authentication.

In wireshark I observe the usual TLS messages:

- client->server: Client Hello
- server->client: Server Hello,
  Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello
  Done
- client->server: Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Certificate
  Verify, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

Now HAProxy answers with: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Decrypt Error)

So my question is: what can cause this type of error?

Comment: RFC5246: "A handshake cryptographic operation failed, including being unable  to correctly verify a signature or validate a Finished message. This message is always fatal."

Answer (score 0):

In this case the cause of the error is very simple:
I've used the wrong CA cert in the haproxy config.